# Python - How to scrape multiple dynamically updated forms / webpages?

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've been trying to scrape a dynamically updated website, each webpage containing hundreds of rows, and the website in total has thousands of of pages (as in each page is accessed by clicking a "next" button or a number on the bottom of the page, just like you see in the bottom of a Google search page).

While I've been able to successfully scrape the pages, I've had trouble getting 100% accuracy in my results namely because the pages are dynamically updated (javascript). When a user logs in to their account, the system puts them back to the very top of the first row of the first page. So, for example, if I were just about to scrape page 101, and I were on page 100, and a user on page 101 logs in to their account, then I would miss that user's info. Considering the volume of activity, this can be quite problematic.

I tried running my automation during the wee hours, but realized there were users world-wide, so that was a fail. I also can't scrape pages in parallel because the forms are accessed/uploaded through javascript and I've had to use Selenium to click through one page at a time. (There's no unique URL per page; I've also tried looking through my browser's Network tab, but there's no variable that changes when I click on another page). I also tried accessing the API [following the instructions on here](http://www.gregreda.com/2015/02/15/web-scraping-finding-the-api/), but the link that I was able to obtain only displays the information on the current page -- so it's no different than what I was able to access through the HTML source.

What are my options? **Is there someway I can catch all the information at once so that I don't risk missing any information?**

I know there will be people asking for the URL, but unfortunately I can't give it away. Even if I did, I couldn't give away the username and password. I'm a beginner at web-scraping, so any help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If you've got no problem hitting the page as many times as you want, and the information never disappears, just go through all the pages as fast as you can, over and over again.  In Selenium you can control multiple tabs and/or browsers simultaneously all using the same cookie to make your scraping faster.